# Loopback datasource specific configs in model

Tags: loopbackjs

Our software is used in MariaDB and Mssql enviroments, at the moment we have specific Loopback instances for different databases, models are the same. Is there way to define datasource specific conifguration to model.

```
 {
    "name": "Album",
    "plural": "album",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "idInjection": false,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "uuid": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultFn": "uuid",
            "id": true
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string"
            //IS IT POSSIBLE TO ADD DATASOURCE CONFIGS HERE?

        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set specific datasource to model in `model-config.json`

```
"your-model": {
    "public": true,
    "dataSource": "your-data-source-name",
 }
```

You can set datasources names in your `datasource.json` file.

Comment: Can I set specific configurations for example description, as in MariaDb use text and and in MSSQL varchar(500)?

Comment: I think I don't understand. Do you want to use one model with two different datasources?

Comment: Yep with two datasource, so I could change it on the settings and configurate database columns in model.